# Android Layout Parameters. Can i change them at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android need bit help..
Is it possible to implement or make layout parameter change according to user's click? or can assign twice

Frankly Can I have

```
RelativeLayout layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

listView1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and then after user click's

```
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);

listView1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Like this structure.

I'm getting an error.

Comment: And include your LogCat, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating layout parameters of type `relative layout` and adding it to `listview`...
layout params you create should be of type as of parent...so create them for listview as below

```
listview01.setLayoutParams(new
   LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

hope this helps.